# "Search Everything" without getting UAC popup on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uac, file-search

Since I've updated to Windows 10, Search Everything always ask for an UAC.
I run this application as an service and have already unchecked the 'run as administrator' (this is the suggested solution in other post).

<sub>(This question has been asked before, for Windows 7, but the solution provided there seems to be obsolete.)</sub>

Comment: What is *"Search Everything"*? From [voidtools](http://voidtools.com/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run setup again and select to install `Everything` as Windows service.

[image]

Now the 2nd everything.exe runs with normal user permissions without any UAC prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling UAC in Windows 10 should never be suggested, as the launch contracts for applications using the UWP rely heavily on the feature.
With UAC disabled, you will lose the ability to use various "Modern" applications - and new core components are being transferred to this model in each build.
Examples of applications and components that could be affected and lose functionality are the ShellExperienceHost , Cortana, and in 1703 ...File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Write permission to installation folder may require administrator rights, using "%APPDATA%\Everything" should not require administrator rights.

Answer (score -1):

You have to disable or lower the UAC in Windows 10. There are two ways to do so:

Option 1: Change User Account Control Settings in **Control Panel**

Option 2: Change User Account Control Settings using a **REG file**

Steps for option 1:

1. Open **Control panel**.
2. Click **user accounts** icon.
3. **Click Change User Account Control** settings. (If you get a **UAC** prompt click **yes**)
4. **Slide** the **slider** down to each level and click **ok**
5. Try running search everything. **Repeat step 4** until desired outcome is achieved.

Steps for Option 2:

1. **Open** Registry Editor by pressing **Windows + R** key combination, type in **regedit** and press **Enter**.
2. If prompted by **UAC**, click on **Yes** to continue.
3. Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**
4. In right-side pane, look for a **EnableLUA** and set the value to **0** and close Registry Editor. (If you do not have this DWORD value, then create it.)
5. **Restart** your computer.

Thank you.

Comment: @KinameCole if  you are copying content from somewhere then you must still provide the link for attribution. Preferably your copied content should also be in a block quote to show what is yours and what isn't. Read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I would add that this is a dangerous course of action. You buy convenience with security. The UAC is there for good reasons. Yes, the answer will solve the problem of the UAC appearing, but the more sensible solution is to grant the Everything Search Engine the proper privileges.

Answer (score -1):

I found I had to install the `x86` version, NOT the `x64` version, using magicandre1981 suggestion to install `Everything` as a Windows service.

Specifically, `Everything-1.4.1.935.x86-Setup.exe` worked,
`Everything-1.4.1.935.x64-Setup.exe` did not work.

Comment: Sounds like you had a 32-bit version of Windows installed.  The accepted answer just recommended *Everything* in general.  Rest assured both versions actually work.

Comment: @Ramhound. Sorry, it didn't work for me. I tried it several times. It could be that my newer version of _Everything_ has this issue. Here is my system information: Edition: Windows 10 Pro. Version: 1903. Installed on: 2019-09-03. OS build: 18362.535
System type: 64-bit operating system. x64-base processor.
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz.  Please remove the down vote if I am not an idiot. Thanks. I am just trying to be helpful in case someone was in my position.